# Does $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2x +3}{\sqrt {x^3 + 2x + 5}} \,dx $ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does the following integral converge? I will post my solution, but I am unsure if it is true.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2x +3}{\sqrt {x^3 + 2x + 5}} \,dx $$

---

**My solution**

Let 
$$ g(x) = \frac{2x}{\sqrt {x^3}}$$ 
$$ f(x) = \frac{2x +3}{\sqrt {x^3 + 2x + 5}} $$
Then $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$$

Therefore whatever one does, so does the other.

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt {x}} = +\infty $$
Therefore g(x) diverges, thus 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2x +3}{\sqrt {x^3 + 2x + 5}} \,dx = + \infty$$ 
diverges too

Comment: This works, but be careful about using something like '$f\sim g$ therefore whatever one does, so does the other' - it works for the way you're using it, but there are many instances where this can get you into trouble, especially when the functions can oscillate between positive and negative.

Comment: Thanks man, that was a concern I had!

Comment: A more rigorous way to do it might be something like 'there exists $X$ such that if $x>X$ then $f(x) \geq x^{-1/2}$. Therefore $\int_X^\infty f(x) \geq \int_X^\infty x^{-1/2}=\infty$.'

Comment: @ThomasBloom The limit form of the comparison test is completely rigorous provided its hypotheses are satisfied. But I agree that someone could use it in a careless way and end up with something wrong. In fact, OP's use is a bit questionable since the second integral introduces a singularity at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that:
$$\frac{2x+3}{\sqrt{x^3+2x+5}}\approx x^{-0.5}$$ for large $x$ and we know that:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^n+c}dx$$
only converges for $c>0,n>1$

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. It's an example of a comparison test (described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test#For_integrals), albeit with explicit squeezing, which $\sim$ implies can be done).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps  redundant:

Let $x \ge 2$.

$\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{3x^3}}\lt \dfrac{2x+3}{\sqrt{x^3+2x+5}}$, or

$0<g(x):=(1/√3)x^{-1/2} <$

$\dfrac{2x+3}{\sqrt{x^3+2x+5}}=:f(x);$

$\int_{2}^{\infty} g(x)dx$ diverges, so does $\int_{2}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ (Monotonicity of integral).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{2x +3}{\sqrt {x^3 + 2x + 5}} \,dx > \int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt {2x^3 }} \,dx= \bigg| \sqrt {2x} \bigg|_{3}^{\infty}=\infty$$
You're correct. The integral diverges.